# Выравнивание блоков css, сдвиги без причин и адаптив

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, adaptive

Возникла проблема. При открытии теста на адаптивность и выборе маленьких экранов, все блоки начинают примыкать к левому краю. Также и с footer, логотип заезжает за экран и весь блок уезжает в лево. Код прилагается https://codepen.io/ivkozelko/pen/PopgoaG
Благодарю заранее.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@300;400;700;900&family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400;500;700&display=swap');
body{
    color: #444444;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

li{
    list-style-type: none;
}

.header-menu{
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.header-menu a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #989898;
}

.header-menu a:hover{
    color: #000;
    transition: 0.3s;
}


.header-menu li{
    flex-grow: wrap;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
}

.header-menu_list li:not(:last-child){
    margin-right: 60px;
}

.header-menu ul{
    display: inline;
}

.header-menu_list{
    display: flex;
}

.header-menu_shopping-cart img{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    float: right;
}

.menu{
    display: none;
}

footer{
    max-width: 100%;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
}

.footer-list{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.footer-column li:first-child{
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.footer-column li:not(:last-child){
    margin-bottom: 13px;
}

.footer-column a{
    color: #1c1c1c;

}

@media (max-width: 950px){
    .header-menu_list{
        display: none;
    }
    .menu{
        cursor: pointer;
        display: block;
    }
    .menu img{
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
    }

    .header-menu{
        justify-content: space-betweenx;
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>magick-box</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
            <div class="header-menu">
                <div class="menu"><img src="img/menu.png" alt=""></div>
                <div class="logo">
                    <h1>logotype</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="header-menu_list">
                    <div class="burger">
                    <ul class="header-menu_list">
                        <li class="header-menu_list_item"><a href="">Главная</a></li>
                        <li class="header-menu_list_item"><a href="">Каталог</a></li>
                        <li class="header-menu_list_item"><a href="">Оплата и доставка</a></li>
                        <li class="header-menu_list_item"><a href="">Контакты</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="header-menu_shopping-cart">
                    <img src="img/shopping-cart.png" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
    </header>
    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="footer-list">
            <div class="first-column"><h1>logotype</h1></div>
                <ul class="footer-column">
                    <li>Сервис</li>
                    <li><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Доставка</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Отзывы</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Оплата</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Возврат</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="footer-column">
                    <li>Каталог</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Подарочные наборы</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Конструктор</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Скидки</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="footer-column">
                    <li>Дополнительная информация</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Реквизиты</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Публичный договор</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Реквизиты</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Поставщики</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
<script src="scripts/script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Может банально увеличить тег отвечающий за задний фон на 100%?